# Error connecting to Postgres database from UWP application

Tags: postgresql, uwp, .net-core, npgsql

Trying to connect to a Postgres database from a UWP app using Npgsql and getting an error loading the following assembly:

```
"System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

And this is the exact exception:

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<RawOpen>d__139.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__136.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<AllocateLong>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at ... >>> here goes my code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/820.

Unfortunately you'll have a few months until UWP supports netstandard20, at which point this will go away.